# ListPreference changes being ignored in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Why is my `ListPreference` not executing the desired actions whenever the preference changes? I followed [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVPvh1t9ZPI) but for some reason, the listener is not working. I haven't seen any working tutorials in Kotlin on how to do this.

**root_preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="reply"
        app:entries="@array/reply_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
        app:key="list_reply"
        app:title="@string/reply_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**arrays.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Reply Preference -->
    <string-array name="reply_entries">
        <item>Reply</item>
        <item>Reply to all</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="reply_values">
        <item>reply</item>
        <item>reply_all</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Activity**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

       val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
       sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        //...
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
        when (key){
            "reply" -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Reply selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            "reply_to_all" -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Reply To All selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`?

Comment: In the `onCreate` method

Comment: Since your `ListPreference` key is `list_reply`, if you add a branch for that to your `when`, does it get control?

Comment: @CommonsWare do I add `when (key)` inside the branch or `when (something else)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
    when (key){
        "reply" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Reply selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        "reply_to_all" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Reply To All selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

This will get called when a value in your `SharedPreferences` changes. The `key` is the key associated with the changed preference value. In the case of `SharedPreferences` being shown on-screen, that key comes from `android:key` or `app:key`.

In your case, your `app:key` is `list_reply`:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="reply"
        app:entries="@array/reply_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
        app:key="list_reply"
        app:title="@string/reply_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Your `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` function, right now, will completely ignore this, as you are not looking for `list_reply`. You need to add a branch to your existing `when` to cover `list_reply`, such as:

```
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
    when (key){
        "reply" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Reply selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        "reply_to_all" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Reply To All selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        "list_reply" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The user chose something from the ListPreference -- get the updated value from the SharedPreferences", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And, if `reply` and `reply_to_all` are not really keys, you could do something like:

```
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
    when (key) {
        "list_reply" -> {
            if (sharedPreferences.getString(key, "reply") == "reply") {
              // TODO
            }
            else {
              // TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MacaronLover: "Should "reply" and "reply_to_all" be inside the "list_reply" branch?" -- probably. You have `reply` and `reply_to_all` as candidate values of the `list_reply` preference. Those are *values*, not *keys*. Your `when` is looking at the key. If you want to take particular actions when the user changes the value associated with the `list_reply` key, replace the `Toast` with code that retrieves the now-current `list_reply` preference value and takes some action based upon it.

Comment: How do I check the value that was selected within the `list_reply` key? I understand about the values not being keys so obviously they won't be executed.

Comment: @MacaronLover: "How do I check the value that was selected within the list_reply key?" -- the same way that you read any `SharedPreferences` value. In your case, call `getString()` on the `SharedPreferences` to get the value associated with your desired key.

Comment: It's been a long day. `onSharedPreferenceChanged` only  contains `sharedPreferences` and `key` so do I need to create a new `if` statement to call `getString()`?

Comment: @MacaronLover: "do I need to create a new if statement to call getString()?" -- presumably. See my updated answer. "It's been a long day" -- have a macaron! :-)

Comment: Your suggestion gives an error: `No value passed for parameter 'defValue'`

Comment: @MacaronLover: Sorry, I was doing this from memory. See the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

`reply` and `reply_to_all` are not keys of preferences. Key of your preference is `list_reply`. You can use a way like this.

```
       when (key){
            "list_reply" -> {
                val preference = sharedPreferences as? ListPreference
                if(preference?.value.equals("reply")){
                    //Your code
                }else if(preference?.value.equals("reply_all")){
                    //Your code
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: The `"reply"` and `"reply_all"` preference values are not being executed when I select either of them.

Comment: Then you check what value is selected using `System.out.println(preference?.value)`